# How to exclude resource file from spring boot jar?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using `maven-spring-boot` plugin for jar generating. I have multiple resource files with configuration (`application-production.yml, application-test.yml, application-development.yml`).

Thing is, when I generate the release for our customers, I would like to exclude development and test files. Is it possible to exclude resource file in `maven-spring-boot` plugin?

I tried this:

```
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>application-dev*</exclude>
                        <exclude>application-test*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
```

but the maven plugin uses its own scripts for resource management (for example @val@ replacing etc.) and it fails during packaging if it is added to pom:

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character @ '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 4, column 18:
    project.version: @project.version@
```

without it, it works ok.

Comment: Why do you want to exclude them? Is it because you don't want them to be able to see those files are because they're causing errors? Spring boot supports multiple `application-{profile}.yml` files by default, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, I do not want for each release to delete the files which should not be visible for the customer (password for test/dev db etc.). Another option is to run the spring boot jar with parameters and thus to set all required values - but not definitely comfortable.

Comment: You can also have an external `application.properties` file (in the same folder as your application JAR/WAR).

Comment: I am sure that with some Maven tweaks you can accomplish your goal, but I would argue that you shouldn't be creating artifacts in this way. The produced jar should not contain the production properties, rather those should be external to the jar, and can automatically be picked up by Spring Boot if you follow [these](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) conventions

Comment: @g00glen00b, one reason you'd want to exclude them is to keep dev/test artifacts out of your production deliveries. Many code scanners would consider their presence a security finding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using maven-spring-boot plugin use maven-resource plugin and maven profiles:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <directory>[your directory]</directory>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>[non-resource file #1]</exclude>
            <exclude>[non-resource file #2]</exclude>
            <exclude>[non-resource file #3]</exclude>
            ...
            <exclude>[non-resource file #n]</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Make sure you specify `<filtering>true</filtering>` option inside resource element.

Create one profile for each environment and filter those files.

Make sure to execute maven with the proper profile:

```
mvn clean install -P prod
```

To view more examples of maven-resource plugin take a look at [maven-resource](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)

If you want to learn more about profiles, take a look at [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: maven-resource plugin does not use in-place editing of properties values. That's why you cannot use @project.version@ in your properties files.

Comment: Make sure you've specified `<filtering>true</filtering>`

Comment: Thank you for this. Finally I came back to this thread and really, you solved that .. Great!

Answer (score 12):

The Spring Boot Maven plugin repackages the JAR file created by the Maven JAR Plugin. So you also have the option to simply exclude files when the JAR is first built, which keeps the Spring Boot Maven plugin from finding them in the first place:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
             <exclude>application-dev*</exclude>
             <exclude>application-test*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is the best and cleanest solution IMHO, allowing to keep using spring boot maven plugin.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the profiles. Normally, resources are excluded per profile and in the answer the profile is not covered.

Comment: i like the generic approach because i want it apply to all profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Using maven-resources-plugin, it support excludes tag.

By the way, why you need to use three yaml files? you can write those configuration in one application.yaml file with "---" and spring.profiles, like:

```
memcached.addresses: test03:11211
spring.profiles.active: dev
---
# dev
spring:
    profiles: dev
logging.access.enabled: false
---
# test
spring:
    profiles: test
logging.config: classpath:log4j.test.properties
logging.access.dir: /home/shared/log
---
# online
spring:
    profiles: online
logging.config: classpath:log4j.online.properties
logging.access.dir: /home/shared/log
```

Comment: Spring boot also supports multiple `application-{profile}.yml` files out of the box.

Comment: maven-resource-plugin does not support in-place replacing of @value@ tags. boot plugin makes all that