# Instruct Hibernate to ignore hibernate.properties

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

We are including a jar dependency that contains the `hibernate.properties` file, thus it ends on the classpath, which is read by our Spring Boot application during startup and causing confusion, since it prints the following line in the console:

```
INFO 11876 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.c.Environment                        : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=, ...
```

How can we instruct Hibernate to ignore this file?

Comment: You can use maven-resource plugin to filter out the hibernate.properties file from the classpath in the first place. Try the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840749/how-to-exclude-resource-file-from-spring-boot-jar

Comment: @Sander_M as I understand, this solution is for the final artifact build? I tried this, and it doesn't work from an IDE.